# Python corrupting pptx files

Tags: python-3.x, zip, powerpoint, lxml, openpyxl

I unzipped a pptx file into a folder structure of xml files by renaming it to .zip. Next I edited some data (no structural changes just some minor data changes and some charts/tables data changes). Then when I re-zipped the file and renames it to .pptx, it says the file has been corrupted. I am using linux and editing the files with :

- xml files with : from lxml import etree as ET
- xlsx : import openpyxl

Any help will be appreciated. Thank in advance.

Edit:
Please find the code snippets below
[Snippet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PF8xD.png)
[Snippet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4IiB.png)

Edit 2 :
Even when I dont change anything in the file, just open it read and print stuff then also I am not able to convert it back to a pptx

Edit 3:
def getStringFromFile(filename):

```
wordsFromTheFIle = []
tree = ET.parse(filename)
root = tree.getroot()
ns = {'a': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main',
      'r': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships',
      'p': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/presentationml/2006/main'}

subroot= root.find('p:cSld', ns)
sptree = subroot.find('p:spTree', ns)
for sp in sptree.findall('p:sp', ns):
    txBody = sp.find('p:txBody', ns)
    for p in txBody.findall('a:p', ns):
        for r in p.findall('a:r',ns):
            for t in r.findall('a:t',ns):
                word = t.text
                if(word!=None):
                    wordsFromTheFIle.append(word)
                    

print(wordsFromTheFIle)
```

And reading the files in this format:

```
filenames = glob("Path to files")
for filename in filenames:
     print(filename)
     getStringFromFile(filename)
```

Edit 4 :

```
with zipfile.ZipFile("/path-to-pptx/_MyPresentation.pptx", 'r') as zip_ref:
zip_ref.extractall("path-to-extract-folder")
zip_ref.close()

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile('another.pptx', 'w')
zip_file.write('_MyPresentation')
zip_file.close()
```

Even this seems to corrupt files on my machine

Comment: Did you try your process without making any change to the pptx ?

Comment: @EricMathieu yes I did. And that works fine!!

Comment: @mzjn I have added code snippets. Sorry I cannot add the actual pptx files here :(

Comment: Why is the question tagged with "openpyxl"? Isn't this about Powerpoint?

Comment: @mzjn I have added the code snippets in edit 3. And I tagged openpyxl because I am using that library to read an xlsx file inside the pptx. Was not sure which was causing the issue

Comment: @EricMathieu Sorry I thought you asked if the unzipping and rezipping works. That works but merely reading the file with python and rezipping back also doesnt seem to work

Comment: Something you are doing **is** changing the files within the zip archive. Work with a copy.

Comment: @CharlieClark Could you kindly explain what do you mean by working with a copy? I have to regenerate the pptx file after all the operations by rezipping manually anyhow

Comment: @BitastaB I believe you do not need "with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:", since ET just needs the filename. It may be a conflict issue with the same file being open twice

Comment: @BitastaB Can you run `unzuip -lv filename` against the original pptx file and the one you've written? That will give us more details on what is different with the two files.

Comment: @pmqs you're correct..it has somehow added about 15 files to the zip.. every file is now wrapped in a new folder for instance: ppt/slides/_rels/slide3.xml.rels is now inside  _MyPresentation/ppt/slides/_rels/slide3.xml.rels

Comment: @EricMathieu thanks for telling me that..It didnt solves this issue but its good to know where I have coded unnecessary stuff! :)

Comment: @BitastaB I coded your example and have no problem. Can you provide your "glob" command parameter?

Comment: @EricMathieu Its :glob( "_MyPresentation/ppt/slides/*.xml") . I also tried edit 4: where I just unzip a pptx file from python and rezip it as a pptx. That also doesnot seem to work. Can it be a machine specific problem?

Comment: @BitastaB It could be interesting to have the actual code for zip_file.write since the issue is obviously related to that.

Comment: @EricMathieu umm the param inside the glob command is the actual code. I just changed the presenttation file name to MyPresentation. And : zipfile.ZipFile("/home/bitasta/PycharmProjects/MyWorkspace/_MyPresentation.pptx", 'r') as zip_ref:

Comment: @BitastaB I cannot see any glob in the edit 4

Comment: @BitastaB Cou you please try this piece of code on your machine ? Example.pptx can be any pptx and you can replace the path with any other. It works great on my machine

Comment: import zipfile
import os

with zipfile.ZipFile("g:\Temp\Example.pptx", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall("g:\Temp\Test")
    zip_ref.close()

zip_file2 = zipfile.ZipFile(r'G:\Temp\Test\another.pptx', 'w')
os.chdir("G:\Temp\Test")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if file != "another.pptx":
            print(os.path.join(root, file))
            zip_file2.write(os.path.join(root, file))
zip_file2.close()

Comment: @EricMathieu :( I tried but still not working. getting the same "The file 'another_new.pptx' is corrupt and therefore cannot be opened. LibreOffice can try to repair the file.

The corruption could be the result of document manipulation or of structural document damage due to data transmission.

We recommend that you do not trust the content of the repaired document.
Execution of macros is disabled for this document.

Should LibreOffice repair the file?
"